# Run through two sequences in one loop

Tags: command-line, bash, sh

I'm trying to run through two sequences in the same loop in my shell like below:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in (1..15) and (20..25) ;
do
     echo $i
     ......
     .....other process
done
```

any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: @zanna -- my first thought is that the boolean "and" is exclusive, meaning that the result are the numbers that exist on both sets; which is none in this  case. Is there an inclusive "and" ?

Comment: @ravery I put "and" just to explain what i'm looking for

Comment: @YassineSihi --  Well make note. Many new programmers stumble on this point until they can retrain their brain, because spoken language uses "and" inclusively but the logical "and" is exclusive in most programming languages.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You only need brace expansion for that

```
$ for n in {1..3} {200..203}; do echo $n; done
1
2
3
200
201
202
203
```

We can pass a list to `for` (`for i in x y z; do stuff "$i"; done`).

So here, braces `{` `}` get the shell to expand your sequences into a list. You only need put a space between them, since the shell splits lists of arguments on those.

Comment: Yep, braces . . . And you don't even need a loop for that ^_0

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I figure they don't actually just want to `echo` the numbers

Comment: yep, if they want to some sort of action, like `touch` files, they can just do `touch {1..15}.txt {20..25}.txt` , no loop needed here. But of course if it's multiple actions  on same number - OK, that could use a loop.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively we can use `seq` (*print a sequence of numbers*), here are two equivalent examples:

```bsh
for i in `seq 1 3` `seq 101 103`; do echo $i; done
```

```bsh
for i in $(seq 1 3) $(seq 101 103); do echo $i; done
```

---

If it is a script, for repetitive tasks, you can use functions:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
my_function() { echo "$1"; }
for i in {1..3}; do my_function "$i"; done
for i in {101..103}; do my_function "$i"; done
```

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
my_function() { for i in `seq $1 $2`; do echo "$i"; done; }
my_function "1" "3"
my_function "101" "103"
```

Answer (score 4):

[Zanna's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/968555/429680) and [pa4080's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/968561/429680) are both good and I'd probably go with one of them in most circumstances. Perhaps it goes without saying, but for the sake of completeness, I'll say it anyway: You can load each value into an array and then loop over the array. For example:

```
the_array=( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 20 21 22 23 24 25 )
for i in "${the_array[@]}";
do
    echo $i
done
```

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy:  Thanks the feedback. I'm old enough that that is how I was taught, and still usually do it on the rare occasion I'm writing a shell script. However, I've updated the answer to use an array.

Comment: Very well !  Happy scripting !

Answer (score 3):

## Looping without a loop

Zanna's answer is absolutely correct and well suited for bash, but we can improve that even more without utilizing a loop.

```
printf "%d\n"  {1..15} {20..25}
```

Behavior of `printf` is such that if the number of `ARGUMENTS` is greater than format controls in `'FORMAT STRING'`, then `printf` will split all `ARGUMENTS`  into equal chunks and keep fitting them to the format string over and over until it runs out of `ARGUMENTS` list.

If we're striving for portability, we can utilize `printf "%d\n"  $(seq 1 15) $(seq 20 25)` instead

Let's take this further and more fun. Say we want to perform an action rather than just printing numbers. For creating files out of that sequence of numbers, we could easily do `touch {1..15}.txt {20..25}.txt`. What if we want multiple things to occur? We could also do something like this:

```
$ printf "%d\n" {1..15} {20..25} | xargs -I % bash -c 'touch "$1.txt"; stat "$1.txt"' sh %
```

Or if we want to make it old-school style:

```
printf "%d\n" {1..15} {20..25} | while read -r line; do 
    touch "$line".txt;
    stat "$line".txt;
    rm "$line".txt; 
done
```

---

## Portable but verbose alternative

If we want to make a script solution that works with shells that don't have brace expansion ( which is what `{1..15} {20..25}` relies on) , we can write a simple while loop:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
start=$1
jump=$2
new_start=$3
end=$4

i=$start
while [ $i -le $jump ]
do
    printf "%d\n" "$i"
    i=$((i+1))
    if [ $i -eq $jump ] && ! [ $i -eq $end ];then
        printf "%d\n" "$i"
        i=$new_start
        jump=$end
    fi
done
```

Of course this solution is more verbose, some things could be shortened, but it works. Tested with `ksh`, `dash`, `mksh`, and of course `bash`.

---

## Bash C-style loop

But if we wanted to make a loop bash-specific ( for whatever reason, perhaps not just printing but also doing something with those numbers ), we can also do this (basically C-loop version of the portable solution) :

```
last=15; for (( i=1; i<=last;i++ )); do printf "%d\n" "$i"; [[ $i -eq $last ]] && !  [[ $i -eq 25 ]] && { i=19;last=25;} ;done
```

Or in more readable format:

```
last=15
for (( i=1; i<=last;i++ )); 
do 
    printf "%d\n" "$i"
    [[ $i -eq $last ]] && !  [[ $i -eq 25 ]] && { i=19;last=25;} 
done
```

---

## Performance comparison of different looping approaches

```
bash-4.3$ time bash -c 'printf "%d\n" {0..50000}>/dev/null'

real    0m0.196s
user    0m0.124s
sys 0m0.028s
bash-4.3$ time bash -c 'for i in {1..50000}; do echo $i > /dev/null; done'

real    0m1.819s
user    0m1.328s
sys 0m0.476s
bash-4.3$ time bash -c ' i=0;while [ $i -le 50000 ]; do echo $i>/dev/null; i=$((i+1)); done'

real    0m3.069s
user    0m2.544s
sys 0m0.500s
bash-4.3$ time bash -c 'for i in $(seq 1 50000); do printf "%d\n" > /dev/null; done'

real    0m1.879s
user    0m1.344s
sys 0m0.520s
```

## Non-shell alternative

Just because we can here's Python solution

```
$ python3 -c 'print("\n".join([str(i) for i in (*range(1,16),*range(20,26))]))'
```

Or with a bit of shell:

```
bash-4.3$ python3 << EOF
> for i in (*range(16),*range(20,26)):
>    print(i)
> EOF
```

Comment: I've just tested `touch $(printf "%d\n"  {1..15} {20..25})` :-)

Comment: @pa4080 actually for `bash` you don't even need `$()` there, just `touch {1..15}.txt  {20..25}.txt`  :)  But of course we could use `printf "%d\n` {1..15} {20..25}` with `xargs` if we wanted to do more than just `touch` files.  There's many ways to do things and  it makes scripting so much fun !